# Evaluate this finite product

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $$\prod_{n=0}^{99} 2n + 1$$

I tried with partial products but I have no clue. Can I be given a hint?

Comment: is it product over $2n$ or $2n+1$?

Comment: See [double factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Comment: Is $\prod_{n=0}^{99}\left(2n+1\right)$ or $\prod_{n=0}^{99}2n+1$?

Comment: I would guess it is the former, otherwise the problem is trivial.

Comment: Presumably, this is related to his [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1234316/find-the-largest-k-such-that-3k-divides-the-product-of-the-first-100-odd#1234326) involving $\prod_{n=0}^{99}\left(2n+1\right)$ .

Answer (score 1):

$$\prod_{n=0}^{99} 2n + 1=\prod_{1\leq k\leq 199\text{ and } n\text{ odd}}k=\frac{\prod_{1\leq k\leq 199}k}{\prod_{1\leq k\leq 199\text{ and } n\text{ even}}k}$$

$$\prod_{n=0}^{99} 2n + 1=\frac{199!}{{\prod_{k=1}^{99}2k}}=\frac{199!}{2^{99}\times99!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(2n+1)!! = \frac{(2n+1)!}{(2n)!!} = \frac{(2n + 1)!}{n!2^n}$

Comment: How does the factorial form help?

Comment: $$(2n + 1)!! = \prod_{k=0}^{m} (2n - 2k + 1)$$

How is that equivalent to my product?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow: $(2n+1)!!  = 1 \cdot 3 \ldots (2n+1) = \prod_{k=0}^{n}(2k+1)$

Comment: mmm... how do you represent a double factorial like that? I know:

$$(2n + 1)! = 1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2n + 1)$$ But how is the double-factorial of that the same?

Comment: multiply denominator and numerator by $(2n)!!$